# How to find a holder of a property

Tags: entity-framework, linq

In the following example in Entity Framework, how to find the author of a specified book using linq:

```
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Title { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think type of  `Title` Book is `int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a collection of `authors`, you would simply do

```
var author = authors.SingleOrDefault(x=> x.Books.Any(y=> y.Title.Equals(bookTitle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

This assumes that books have only one author.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it in this simple way, [Demo on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uie4dE)

```
var result = authors.SelectMany(a => a.Books.Select(b => new { BookTitle = b.Title, AuthorName = a.AuthorName }));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Amir Parsi